# ¿Como puedo hacer el efecto de palabras que se escriben sola con Java?

Tags: java, java-8

¿Hay alguna manera más cómoda de hacer este efecto en java?

Estuve haciendo algunas aplicaciones de consola como práctica y pensé que seria genial añadirle este efecto pero no se como hacerlo sin escribir mucho código.

```
public class EfectoDeLetras{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i=0;

        while(i<10){
            try{
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.print("H");
            i++;
        }
        i=0;

        while(i<10){
            try{
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.print("HO");
            i++;
        }
        i=0;

        while(i<10){
            try{
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.print("HOL");
            i++;
        }
        i=0;

        while(i<10){
            try{
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.print("HOLA");
            i++;
        }
        i=0;

        while(i<10){
            try{
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.print("HOLA ");
            i++;
        }
        i=0;

        while(i<10){
            try{
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.print("HOLA M");
            i++;
        }
        i=0;

        while(i<10){
            try{
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.print("HOLA MU");
            i++;
        }
        i=0;

        while(i<10){
            try{
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.print("HOLA MUN");
            i++;
        }
        i=0;

        while(i<10){
            try{
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.print("HOLA MUND");
            i++;
        }
        i=0;

        while(i<10){
            try{
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.print("HOLA MUNDO");
            i++;
        }
        i=0;


    }
}
```

He visto algunos ejemplos que utilizan la clase Timer pero lo hacen usando la interfaz gráfica y no la consola, es por eso que no logro entenderla bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por conveniencia puedes hacer un método que haga ese trabajo, que reciba un `String` y que itere mediante un bucle `for` la siguiente cadena que va a mostrar y por último otro bucle `for` que lo repita 10 veces seguida con la misma cadena que se ha extraído.

Ejemplo:

```
public static void printMessage(String message) {
    if (message == null)
        return;
    for (int i = 0 ;  i < message.length() ; i++) {
        String sub = message.substring(0, i + 1);
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {
            try {
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            } catch (Throwable ignored) {}
            System.out.print(sub);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printMessage("HOLA MUNDO");
}
```

**Hacerlo sin que se borre toda la consola**

Hice este otro código para que no se eliminará todo el texto que ya se había sido escrito, elimine el otro bucle `for` que estaba adentro del primero bucle `for` ya que no le veía la necesidad de ejecutarlo 10 veces para lograr el efecto, también borre la llamada del comando de la consola, esas dos cosas del código han sido cambiada por una llamada a `Thread.sleep(long)` y así tener el efecto

```
public static void printMessage(String message) {
    if (message == null)
        return;
    StringBuilder backspaceBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0 ;  i < message.length() ; i++) {
        String sub = message.substring(0, i + 1);
        try {
            /* Para que se note el efecto, ya que antes llamaba 
                a un programa y se tenía que esperar cierto tiempo 
                para que se terminará 10 veces seguidas. De todos 
                modos puedes cambiarlo como gustes :) */
            Thread.sleep(25L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.print(backspaceBuilder.toString() + sub);
        backspaceBuilder.append('\b');
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printMessage("Primer Mensaje");
    printMessage("Segundo Mensaje");
}
```

Comment: Genial si funciona. Entonces dentro del public static void main(String[] args){} puedo escribir mi codigo y cada vez que quiera aplicar el efecto solo tengo que llamar al metodo verdad??? :))

Comment: Exacto, sin necesidad de escribir demasiado código para lograr el efecto

Comment: Si pero hay un inconveniente, cuando quiero que se imprima otra frase me borra toda la pagina pero ya encontre una solucion. Se te ocurre una mejor o esta bien como lo hice??

Comment: Edite la publicación e hice otro código para que no se borre todo el texto de la consola, de todas formas puedes usar el mio o el tuyo, usa el mejor que te parezca :)

Comment: hola.                                                                                                         una pregunta, como puedo cambiar la velocidad??. La verdad es que aun no entiendo bien como funciona tu codigo pero bueno investigare de todos modos. Disculpa mi ignorancia, jeje xD

Comment: Te explico, la velocidad de cómo se muestra el texto varía por el método `sleep(long millis)` de la clase `Thread`, lo que hace es dormir o detener el hilo en donde se está corriendo el código actual con un tiempo de milis-segundos, si quieres aumentar el tiempo de espera incrementa el valor que contiene de `Thread.sleep(25L);` a `Thread.sleep(100L)` que sería 0.1 segundo por ejemplo, o reducir el tiempo de espera como de `Thread.sleep(10L)` sería como 0.010 segundos, [aquí](https://bit.ly/2GSSdzu) ó [aquí](https://bit.ly/2lpSGxm) puedes ver cómo funciona la clase `Thread`

Comment: Gracias, muchas gracias :-)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que seria mejor de esta manera por que asi ya no tendria que borrarse todo para
que se imprima otra frase...

```
 public class printMessage{   
    public static void printMessage(String message) {
        if (message == null)
            return;
        String b="";
        for (int i = 0 ;  i < message.length() ; i++) {
            String sub = message.substring(0, i + 1);
            b=b+"\b";
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {

                String mostrar=sub + b;
                try {
                    new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
                    System.out.print(mostrar);
                } catch (Throwable ignored) {}


            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printMessage("HOLA MUNDO");
        printMessage("Por conveniencia puedes hacer un método que haga ese trabajo");


    }
}
```